# Search Tags but not for bounty?

Tags: feature-request, tags, search

Sometimes I see interesting tags that don't have many posts (bison, osdev, etc.) and I like clicking them to see the most recent few posts about them. I often get ideas or learn about things and I don't need to think of keywords or learn what to search! It appears I can't do this anymore. Can we get that tag search feature back? Also searching multiple tags would be nice.

I do notice I can search for tags by user but hacking the url and removing the user id part doesn't help me search tags. Ok [I tried setting user to 0 and it worked](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A0+%5Blanguage-design%5D%5Bgcc%5D). The functionality is there but can we have a nicer way to access it?

I also like how multiple tags are AND'd. I hated when searches OR them and give me tons of MORE results that I do not want.

Comment: +1, this would help my points ... if people checked their old questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can search within a tag. See

https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search

Comment: Yes but i only get bounty results. I want all results. I use to check bison and osdev. Now they both get no results and unless i hack the userid

Comment: uh, switch tabs. You're on the featured tab. Click a different tab.

Comment: Yike! i completely did not notice it. -1000 for me :(